# Permissions - users delete their name from list from page

Tags: permissions

I have multiple lists representing courses on a page and visitors can sign up for whatever course.  I have made permissions on those lists 'contribute' but not on the page.  People can sign up now, but aren't able to remove themselves because when they mark their name on the list they don't get 'Remove Item' button (I assume because they've no permissions to the page).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The contribute permission level allow you to add, delete ...
And, no, you don't need to, and you should not allow modifications on the page itself.

So why people can't remove items...
Did you modify the contribute permission level ?

Comment: No, I gave them Contribute OOTB permission level to the specific lists.